# What does it mean finely divided aluminum?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Reaction of aluminum with oxygen
Finely divided aluminum Burns with oxygen with a brilliant yellow flame at high temperature and produce white aluminum (aluminum oxide).

Comment: High surface area aluminium, think fine powder.

Comment: It's powdered aluminum.

Comment: Same as in any other context. Who are Finely and Burns?

Answer (score 3):

Finely divided aluminum is a rather thin aluminum powder obtained by evaporating (boiling) liquid aluminum in a high vacuum or an argon atmosphere, and letting cool it down without touching a wall. Oxygen must be absolutely absent.